# Do not close dialog windows till told otherwise?

Tags: android, database, user-interface, android-alertdialog

In a dialog window, user inputs search keyword. Then database looks for it and returns list of objects. If lists size is 0, I would like to notify user that nothing was found and keep dialog windows opened till user is able to enter correct keyword with more than 0 results or till user decides to exit dialog window.

I can't figure out how to keep window opened if no results were found in DB. Help would be appreciated:

```
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    final EditText input = new EditText(getActivity());
    input.setHint("Enter keyword");

    builder.setTitle("Search").setView(input)
            .setPositiveButton("DONE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    newExams = database.searchList(input.getText().toString());
                    if (newExams.size() == 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Nothing!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return;
// here, I would like to make sure that window will be opened for second attempt of inputting a keyword
                    }

                    ExamAdapter newAdapter = new ExamAdapter(getActivity(), newExams);
                    listViewExams.setAdapter(newAdapter);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    // Canceled.
                }
            });
    return builder.create();
}
```

Comment: `builder.setCancelable(false);`?

Comment: @ChrisHandy I've tried that. Had to declare builder as final, and called setCancelable method inside if clause with value false and outside it with value true. Did not seem to help.

Comment: also @ChrisHandy - would like to point out that according to Google's documentation, setCancelable method only determines whether or not user is able to close dialog with a back button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Custom dialog fragment and override your button, there is a working example from my old codes:

```
public class MyAlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {


public static MyAlertDialogFragment newInstance(int title) {
    MyAlertDialogFragment frag = new MyAlertDialogFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("title", title);
    frag.setArguments(args);

    return frag;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    int title = getArguments().getInt("title");
    final View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.dialoglayout, null);

    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            // .setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setTitle(title)
            .setView(view)
            .setPositiveButton(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.dialog_save),
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int whichButton) {
                            //do something
                            dismiss();

                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.dialog_cancel),
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int whichButton) {
                            //do something
                        }
                    })
            .setNeutralButton(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.dialog_clear),
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int whichButton) {

                        }
                    }).create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart(); // super.onStart() is where dialog.show() is actually
                     // called on the underlying dialog, so we have to do
                     // it after this point
        AlertDialog d = (AlertDialog) getDialog();
        if (d != null) {
            Button neutralButton = (Button) d.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL);
            // neutralButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.xloginbutton);
            // neutralButton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
            neutralButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Boolean wantToCloseDialog = false;
                // Do stuff, possibly set wantToCloseDialog to true then...
                if (wantToCloseDialog) {
                    dismiss();
                }

                // else dialog stays open. Make sure you have an obvious way
                // to close the dialog especially if you set cancellable to
                // false.
                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh, I see, so I have to override onStart in order to modify positive button. Thank you! Will try as soon as possible.